# Compiling RTL8192CU wireless driver

Tags: wireless

I'm trying to compile rtl8192 chipset driver for Edimax nano usb wireless modem. I've got the source code of driver from [here](http://www.wireless-driver.com/realtek-rtl8188cus-rtl8192cu-windows-linux-driver-ver1011/). and do this as root:

```
cd ./driver
make
```

The error is:

```
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-486/build M=/home/r1/wireless_driver_rtl8192cu/RTL8192CU/driver/rtl8192CU_linux_v2.0.1212.20101208  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-486/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-486/build'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: What kernel are you using? `uname -r` Is it 2.6?

Comment: uname -r: 2.6.32-5-486

Comment: what happens if you run the install.sh script i.e. `sudo sh ./install.sh` ?

Answer (score 1):

See [the bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/795770) with this driver on 2.6. Apparently it works with the 3.0 kernel and the [Realtek 3.0 driver](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=2&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=277&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2772).